# How to prevent race condition between Jenkins jobs from the same repository when running in parallel

Tags: maven, jenkins, port

In my application I'm running several integration tests in parallel, spread among different maven profiles.

before each intgeration-test step, I'm using fabric8 to start Couchbase container, for which I use the reserve-network-port task (of builder-helper-maven-plugin) in order to allocate avaliable ports to be used by the Couchbase container.

The issue is that, multiple Jenkins jobs (different BB branches) of by (BB) repository are running in parallel on the same Jenkins machine.

from time to time, integration tests init is failed (for one or more profile), on 'address is already binded' error - meaning that 1 of the allocated tcp ports, been reserverd by the reserve-network-port task (of builder-helper-maven-plugin) has been already been allocated by another job.

Is there a way to avoid this race condition? (e.g. using some kind of resource locking when the reserve-network-port task is been execute? other solution?)

Comment: I strongly recommend to use https://www.testcontainers.org/ that makes is possible to start your couchbase within a test from Java code not from the build... and furthermore you can use the mechanisms of Docker to get a port and that will prevent the clash of the ports...

Comment: Have you considered splitting the jobs so each build runs on a different slave? If you're already using Kubernetes, then the Kubernetes plugin allows you to spawn slaves as pods on top of your cluster.